# join by column type

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2  tables like the following.

```
id1 | val | type
1     2     type1
1     4     type2
2     9     type2
2     7     type1

id2|type1|type2
11  2      4
33  7      9

 I need result like this
id1|id2
1   11
2    33
```

I need to check  both type1 and type2 to relate id1 and id2. I tried the following query but it does not work.

```
 select id1,id2 from t1 inner join t2 on (type='type1' and                             
 t1.val=t2.type1)and (type='type2' and t1.val=t2.type2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you want:

```
SELECT
    a.id1,
    t2.id2
FROM
    t2
INNER JOIN
    t1 a ON a.val = t2.type1 AND a.type = 'type1'
INNER JOIN
    t1 b ON b.val = t2.type2 AND b.type = 'type2'
WHERE
    a.id1 = b.id1
```

Comment: Not a very clever solution unfortunately as you would need to join the table for each `type` what if there are 20 different types :S

Comment: Thanks. I got result when I removed where clause.Can you explain why I need this  where clause?

Comment: Say you had a another row in t1 with values id1: 3, val: 2, type: type1.  Without the where clause, the the query would show another row with the value 3 for id1 and the value 11 for id2.  You can see that here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17b49/1/0.  I copied the schema setup from M. Ali so thanks to him for doing that part.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3b2d/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id1 INT,  val INT,  [type] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1 ,    2     ,'type1'),
(1 ,    4     ,'type2'),
(2 ,    9     ,'type2'),
(2 ,    7     ,'type1')


CREATE  TABLE t2(id2 INT,  [type1] VARCHAR(10),  [type2] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
(11 , 2  ,    4),
(33 , 7  ,    9)
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select t1.id1 , t2.id2 
from t1
inner join 
(Select * from t2 t 
      UNPIVOT (Val for [type]  IN ([type1],[type2]))up) t2
ON t1.val = t2.Val and t1.type = t2.type
GROUP BY t1.id1 , t2.id2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3b2d/1/0)**:

```
| id1 | id2 |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |  11 |
|   2 |  33 |
```